# Cannot execute script while its permission is 'x'

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script in the current directory, however, given that:

1. the permission is `-rwxr-xr-x`
2. the script has a shebang `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the file
3. my shell is `/bin/bash`
4. I can execute it using `bash script.sh`

I cannot execute it using `./script.sh`. It gives me:

> bash: ./script.sh: Permission denied

Why is this happening and what is the solution?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- The execution is not allowed because the file is on a filesystem mounted with the "noexec" option. Use `findmnt -u -T .` to find out if that's the case. If you have root privileges, `mount -o remount,exec <dir>` should remove this option.
- The execution is not allowed by [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) policies (SELinux, SMACK, possibly AppArmor). Check the system logs, starting with `journalctl -n 100` and `dmesg`. Bypassing this (if you're the administrator) depends on which MAC system is actually in use.

Comment: Thank you, in my case it is `noexec`. I got confused, I have this disk mount as `/home           ext4    auto,exec,rw,async,user        0       2` in `/etc/fstab`, why is it `noexec`?

Comment: Because you have the `user` option in there.

Comment: What is *MAC* (in this context)? Not *MAC address*, I presume(?).

Comment: Mandatory Access Control

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found it : it is "log2ram"

As I said, I am using Raspbian on a Raspberry 4, and in order to increase the SD lifetime, I placed the logs on RAM, and here we are.

```
===
pi@R4:~/logs $ cat /etc/log2ram.conf
[...]
PATH_DISK="/var/log;/home/pi/logs"
===
```