# any_name.sh (bash) runs in one directory, not in another

Tags: bash, raspbian

I have a problem with a specific directory (under Raspbian)

The shell I use is simple

```
===
pi@R4:~/log $ cat no_no.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "juju"
exit 0
===
```

Problem directory is ~/log :

```
===
pi@R4:~/logs $ ./no_no.sh
-bash: ./no_no.sh: Permission denied
===
```

Using "sudo" :

```
===
pi@R4:~/logs $ sudo ./no_no.sh
sudo: unable to execute ./no_no.sh: Permission denied
===
```

Can execute with explicit "bash" :

```
===
pi@R4:~/logs $ bash  ./no_no.sh
juju
===
```

I copy it to anywhere, as /tmp and it works :

```
===
pi@R4:/tmp $ cp ~/logs/no_no.sh .
pi@R4:/tmp $ ./no_no.sh 
juju
===
```

The /log directory permissions have nothing special,
as far as I can see (but I am quite sure wrong) :

```
===
pi@R4:~ $ ls -d l*
0 drwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi 300 Apr  5 22:13 logs
===
```

Any ideas ?
Any "magic" commands ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? [Cannot execute script while its permission is 'x'](https://superuser.com/q/1452496/432690)

Comment: To learn how to write, handle and execute scripts and all other things in bash; https://www.tldp.org -> Bash guides

Comment: mr Kamil : I have only one single disk, no "mount" problems.
mr Hannu : your line is not helpfull at all. I started working with a PDP-8 back in 1973, so I can say I have written some amount of shells.