# File not executable even with execute bit

Tags: linux, permissions, shell, file-permissions

Why is the following file not executable?

Changing the permissions to 777 doesn't work either - I get the same result. I thought it might be an owner issue, but with 777 that shouldn't be a problem.

```
$ touch a
$ chmod +x a
$ ./a
bash: ./a: Permission denied
```

What's happening here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot execute script while its permission is 'x'](https://superuser.com/q/1452496/432690)

Comment: Yes. Thanks! I have no idea why the FS is mounted as noexec since that's not in the fstab but for now I'll manually remount when I need to exec files on it. Ah, looks like `user` implicitly enables `noexec`.